# Error: "Deferred binding failed for <entrypoint class> (did you forget to inherit a required module)?"

Tags: java, gwt

I am having an issue with my GWT project.  The project compiles, but when I try to debug as Web Application, I get the following errors.  I am new to this so any guidance on how I might troubleshoot this would be appreciated.  Please let me know if you need to see my code, I am happy to post it.

This error message occurs over and over again:

"Failed to create an instance of 'com.gwt....myEntryPointClass' via deferred binding."

```
11:39:03.438 [ERROR] [helpdesktest] Failed to create an instance of 'com.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client.HelpDeskTest' via deferred binding 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client.HelpDeskTest' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
at com.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client.HelpDeskTest.<init>(HelpDeskTest.java:23)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
at com.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client.HelpDeskTest.<init>(HelpDeskTest.java:23)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
```

I get this message in the browser window:

```
Exception while loading module com.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client.HelpDeskTest. See Development  Mode        for    details.
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:503)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:375)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

And finally, I get this message in the console window.

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 806
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that creating an instance of my service:

```
public class HelpDeskTest implements EntryPoint {
private final HelpDeskTestServiceAsync helpDeskTest= GWT.create (HelpDeskTest.class);
```

Here is what I had to change it to:

```
public class HelpDeskTest implements EntryPoint {
private final HelpDeskTestServiceAsync helpDeskTest= GWT.create (HelpDeskTestService.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

`com.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client.HelpDeskTest` is `HelpDeskTest` class really in the package `com.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client`? Usually Java package names should be lower case.

Assuming this is what you wanted, is the module file in the package `com.gwt.HelpDeskTest`? Your next error suggests that the module is at `com.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client.HelpDeskTest`, which is the same as the entrypoint - this doesn't make sense.

The typical GWT project setup has a module file (ending in `.gwt.xml`), and a `client` package, full of client-only code, including the entrypoint itself. For example

```
com/
   company/
      project/
         MyProject.gwt.xml
         client/
            MyProjectEntryPoint.java
            ...
```

The full name for the entrypoint is then `com.company.project.client.MyProjectEntryPoint`, which should be listed in the `<entry-point>` tag in `MyProject.gwt.xml`.

Comment: My module file is located at `com.gwt.HelpDeskTest`  Here is the entry point line from the HelpDeskTest.gwt.xml: `<entry-point class='com.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client.HelpDeskTest'/>`  So, I guess what I am not clear on is what is telling it that "the module is at com.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client.HelpDeskTest" ?

Comment: Your entrypoint should be at `com/gwt/client/HelpDeskTest.java` instead - get rid of the folder with the same name as the .gwt.xml file, and update the `<entry-point>` tag to match